# Execute JavaScript in iOS7 app and Cordova : memory leak and crash

Tags: ios, cordova, memory-leaks, memory-warning

Is there a known bug on iOS7 which can cause a crash of an iOS application which execute JavaScript on a webview ?

Using memory view on Xcode, i see that the memory increase each seconds until the application crashed after severals minutes..

Thanks

Comment: I have been using cordova 3.1 with Xcode 5 and iOS 7 without any problems. Based on what you describe the only thing that comes to my mind is a Javascript code error. Usually the build process does not complain about code errors in JS code, and once you run it on the simulator or device the app just freezes. Can you double check that you don´t have any JS error? Also I suggest to start testing the code from the start by disabling and re-enabling bits of code to detect the problem.